# Диалоговые окна и кнопка Cancel

Tags: android, интерфейс

Мучаюсь таким вопросом. Стоит ли использовать кнопку Cancel в диалоговых окнах? 
С одной стороны это драгоценное место на экране, которое не хотелось бы занимать бесполезной кнопкой, которую успешно заменяет таб по любому другому месту.
С другой есть ведь пользователи, которых отсутствие такой кнопки может ввести в недоумение.
Как быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ты должен принять решение на основе **юзер-экспириенс**. Т.е. **понять**, а какой из этих вариантов больше мил пользователю?

#### Как понять это?

Сначала определись с целевой аудиторией. Например, твоя целевая аудитория - русские. Многие русские пользуются приложением "Вконтакте" для андроид. Попробуй найти какое-то диалоговое окно в этом приложении и посмотреть, какой из двух вариантов применен там и сделай также.

Можно смотреть шире и равняться на приложения, которые используются вообще во всем мире, например Whatsap или Facebook (у последнего вообще миллиард скачиваний, очень распространненый юзер-экспириенс).

Такой подход касается не только диалоговых окон но и вообще любых элементов интерфейса

Comment: А можно посмотреть [официальные гайдлайны](https://material.google.com/) и не мудрить отсебятины.

Comment: Какая же тут отсебятина, если я советую человеку равняться на популярные проекты? К слову а гайдлайнах. Материал дизайн, несомненно, хорош. Я считаю, что было бы здорово, если бы все android-проекты придерживались такого стандарта, как использвоание материал дизайна. Но вот, к примеру, тот же Facebook с его миллиардом скачиваний. Я запускаю его на своем Android 5.0 и вижу, что иконки в тулбаре не имеют рипл эффекта (ай-яй-яй, не по материалу), а выделяются квадратиком как на 4.0.3. Facebook нарушает стандарт еще много где, но остается популярным. Значит ли это, что гайдлайны - не абсолют?

Comment: Я говорю не конкретно о вашем ответе, а общем предпочтении гайдлайнов каким то самодельным придумкам. То, что фейсбук не следует гайдлайнам, говорит не о ущербности последних, а о допущенных вольностях дизайнеров фейсбука. Следуют они гайдлайнам или нет - это сверхпоулярная сеть и пользователю остается мириться с любыми решениями разработчиков (есть гораздо большие проблемы, чем не следование гайдлайнам, вроде неумеренного жора заряда батареи или использования большого количества оперативки) или отказаться вовсе, на что многие не готовы

Answer (score 4):

Есть [гайдлайны](https://material.google.com/) на интерфейс, настоятельно рекомендуется придерживаться именно этих рекомендаций.

Пользователей приводит в недоумение не только отсутствие кнопки отмены, но и любой непривычный "изыск" от слишком оторвавшегося разработчика, не надо всей этой кустарщины - никто ее не оценит, как и не поблагодарит за потраченное впустую на изучение непривычного интерфейса, время, а потом еще и за испорченные нервы, что во всех приложениях "тапать" в одно место, а в вашем - в другое, а если еще "тапая" по привычке, вызываешь что то другое, то шансы закрепиться на смарте у такого приложения сильно уменьшаются.